# Script exits after certain amount of time

Tags: node.js, discord.js, raspbian

I have this node.js Discord bot that is currently running in production. I run it locally on my Raspberry Pi (doesn't get used a lot so it's cheaper for me). Previously it worked fine, but now, after some time the script exits without logging anything special. This is the command I run in the Raspbian terminal to start the script:
`node KMAR.js > plb_log.log 2> plb_error.log &`

I run the same script for another bot, on the same RPi. Whenever I start them at the same time, they seem to crash at the same time aswell. This seems to be 2 weeks (sometimes 3 weeks) after I start. I do make use of node cron, but I only have something scheduled a few times a day. It doesn't seem like this cronjob would have anything to do with it.

With previous versions of the bot this wouldn't happen. However, I couldn't find differences between versions that would cause this behaviour.

If it could help, here's the repo of the project. Older versions are included aswell. https://github.com/jwsteens/plb

To summarize my problem; my code exits not quite randomly, but after a few weeks. I can't figure out why this happens, as I get no error messages and I can't find anything in my code which would lead to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a script that automatically restarts the bot when it crashes or stops.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
while :
do
    yournodepath yourbotpath
    sleep 1
done
```

save it as `start.sh` or something

and then instead of running `node .` you can do

```
chmod 777 start.sh
./start.sh
```

and now it will run forever until you exit the script